# Open Word Document Programatically Sharepoint 2010

Tags: document-library

I have a small problem that I need to open word documents from button click event from SharePoint document library. Can anyone help me on this?

New Word Document opened:

a) A new word document opened from clicking the create button from the main application    insert data and will get saved in the document library directly.

b) Allows user to write data and will get saved by saving the document.

Answer (score 1):

New Document, create a link like this:

```
<a href="/ServerRelativePath/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=/ServerRelativePath/List%20name/Forms/template.xsn&SaveLocation=%2F/ServerRelativePath%2FList%20Name&Source=%2F/ServerRelativePath%2FList%2520Name%2FForms%2FCV%2520AllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1">Create new document</a>
```

To open a special document, create a link like this (providing you have the SPFile object):

```
"http://path/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=http://path/" +       item.File.Url.Replace(" ", "%20") + "&OpenIn=Browser";
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this post to open a word document on click:

[Open word document from codebehind - e.g Response.Write with some javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833081/open-word-document-from-codebehind-e-g-response-write-with-some-javascript)

You can further decide to spit/call this function on client click of any button.